# Correct way of implementing checkServerTrusted for X509TrustManager

Tags: android, ssl, android-security

What is a recommended way how to implement `checkServerTrusted` method for `X509TrustManager`? I need to use reimplement that for ssl pinning, but I can see just this implementation all the time:

```
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
    throws CertificateException {
    if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
        certificates[0].checkValidity();
    } else {
        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
    }
}
```

taken from this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571883/6270838). However it seems to be wrong in my opinion. 
It only checks whether certificate is valid (not expired), but nothing else.

Is there any implementation you could recommend me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was not to use custom `TrustManagers` but just initialize `KeyStore` with my pinned ssl certificate.

Comment: Usually you want to pin the key, not the certificate. Key pinning allows you to rotate certificates frequently, like every 30 days, and that keeps the CRLs small. Small CRLs are important for mobile clients. Depending how big your PKI is, it may be important for desktop clients, too.

Comment: You mean initialize your *trust* store with the certificate.