# App update rejected while uploading for Beta testing

Tags: android, google-play

I was going to upload app for Beta testing at Google Play. But i am getting app rejection, due to app containing an unsafe implementation of TrustManager.

Comment: are you trusting all untrusted urls?? Are you using a TrustManager class to override to accept all certificates?

Comment: Yes i am using TrustManager class, all urls are trusted

Comment: I'm not sure if that is safe to do, but you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530558/how-to-fix-unsafe-implementation-of-x509trustmanager-in-android-app)

Comment: But the thing app is already live. I am going to update the app. So i was going to upload at Beta testing to test In-App purchase.