# App Rejected By Google Play Store due to unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager

Tags: android, android-security, trustmanager, lib

Received this warning From Google Play store:
**Security alert**
Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.
Vulnerable classes:
com.flurry.android.n
Affects APK version 1.

Please if anyone Know how to solve this issue ...  tell me

Comment: can you tell which version you use of Flurry

Comment: this library i m using 
compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')

Comment: may be you have old jar because this issue in prior then 3.4 version

Comment: Please if you have link or tell me how to update my old jar ???

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/

Comment: Thank you .... problem solved

Comment: happy that you solved your problem,...  i share a post that may help other developers http://stackoverflow.com/a/35576059/3187366