# How to disable SSL verification?

Tags: android, okhttp

I tried disable SSL verification in my app, but app crashes in Android 10 in some devices.
I used in my app Retrofit and Okhttp.
Here how I tried to disable SSL verification in my app. I didn't find any solution from the internet.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(
            object : X509TrustManager {
                override fun checkClientTrusted(
                    chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?,
                    authType: String?
                ) {

                }

                override fun checkServerTrusted(
                    chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?,
                    authType: String?
                ) {

                }

                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? {
                    return null
                }
            }
        )

        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
        val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

        val okhttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://example.com")
            .client(okhttp)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            api.loadMain()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({

                }, {
                    Log.d("myLogs", it.message)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

In Android 10 I catch this exception

```
2020-02-07 14:25:43.552 11668-11668/com.example.okhttpexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.okhttpexample, PID: 11668
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.okhttpexample/com.example.okhttpexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required method checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String, String) missing
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required method checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String, String) missing
    at android.net.http.X509TrustManagerExtensions.<init>(X509TrustManagerExtensions.java:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.Android10CertificateChainCleaner.<init>(Android10CertificateChainCleaner.kt:36)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform.buildCertificateChainCleaner(Android10Platform.kt:62)
    at okhttp3.internal.tls.CertificateChainCleaner$Companion.get(CertificateChainCleaner.kt:42)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.kt:735)
    at com.example.okhttpexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This exception from crashlytics. It also happens only in Android 10

```
       Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.okhttpexample/com.example.okhttpexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)


   Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on a, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl
   at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.buildCertificateChainCleaner(Platform.java:151)
   at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:698)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule.provideOkHttpClient(NetworkModule.java:277)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.provideOkHttpClient(NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.java:47)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.java:36)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideOkHttpClientFactory.java:12)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:32)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:11)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideVeonApiFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideVeonApiFactory.java:27)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.NetworkModule_ProvideVeonApiFactory.get(NetworkModule_ProvideVeonApiFactory.java:10)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.api.NetworkHelper_Factory.get(NetworkHelper_Factory.java:42)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.api.NetworkHelper_Factory.get(NetworkHelper_Factory.java:9)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.data.repository.DataRepository_Factory.get(DataRepository_Factory.java:36)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.data.repository.DataRepository_Factory.get(DataRepository_Factory.java:10)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.DaggerApplicationComponent.injectMainActivity(DaggerApplicationComponent.java:600)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.di.DaggerApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerApplicationComponent.java:526)
   at com.example.okhttpexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 1:**

Ensure you are using okhttp with version 4.3.1 or above.

You need to add the following to the proguard file inorder to avoid crash on Android 10.

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
    private final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
}
```

Please note that in my SocketFactory class, I had the following field:

```
private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;
```

So adjust the `ProGuard` rule accordingly. E.g, the access modifiers like private, final, etc. as well as the field name (delegate) should match exactly as written in the class file.

---

You need to add the following to the Application tag in your manifest file to make it work with latest android versions.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains**

```
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };
```

**Install the all-trusting trust manager**

```
 final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
 sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
```

**Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager**

```
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

**Register the sslSocketFactory with OkHttpClient builder**

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

That's all.

Comment: My code like your code, but wrote in Kotlin. But it didn't helped to me

Comment: Did you try to test your code in Android 10 emulator?

Comment: My code crashes in Android 10 emulator and Real device with Android 10

Comment: add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to manifest. see the updated answer

Comment: I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but it didn't help

Comment: Also I have android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" but it didn't help

Comment: are you getting crash on release build?

Comment: Yes, I am getting crash on release build. Crash from Crashlytics from my production app

Comment: Hey TikTak, did you try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530558/how-to-fix-unsafe-implementation-of-x509trustmanager-in-android-app#answer-35576059 ?

Comment: @TikTak see the updated answer. include those rule in your proguard file

Comment: @KévinGiacomino I also tried this solution, but it didn't helped to me

Comment: -keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
    private final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
} it won't help me because I am in debug and in debug minifyEnabled="false" and shrinkResources="false"

Comment: which version of okhttp you use

Comment: I use okhttp 4.3.0

Comment: @TikTak please try with the new release of okhttp "4.3.1". See this post: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5682

Comment: @KévinGiacomino I recently updated my library dependency and it worked.

Comment: @TikTak Please do check my answer it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Android 10 requires an upgraded version of Okhttp, upgrade the version will solve the Required method checkServerTrusted error.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
```